# How can i use math.cos function for list or arange at python

Tags: python, math, typeerror

In my code, I get the below error

> TypeError: must be real number, not list

```py
import numpy as np
x_list=[]
for x in np.arange(1,10,0.01):
    x_list.append(x)
a = math.cos(x_list)
```

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`math.cos()` expects a number and not a list, this is why you are getting the `TypeError`. If you are interested in having a list of cosines out of your `np.arange()` product, you could do:

```py
import numpy as np

x_list = np.arange(1,10,0.01)
x_list = np.cos(x_list)

print(x_list)
```

This will yield a very long list of cosines.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` is the go-to for vectorized mathematical python.  For example you can do this instead:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1,10,0.01)
np.cos(x)
```

It will be many times faster than iteration through a list.